# jQuery increment the ID and href of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a template that looks like this:

```
<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
<div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>

<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
<div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>

<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
<div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>

<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
<div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>
```

I want to take each ID and href element and concatenate a number so they can be unique.

Like this:

```
<a href="#someHref0" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
<div id="someHref0" class="modal fade"></div>

<a href="#someHref1" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
<div id="someHref1" class="modal fade"></div>

<a href="#someHref2" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
<div id="someHref2" class="modal fade"></div>

<a href="#someHref3" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
<div id="someHref3" class="modal fade"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.yourclassname').each(function(i){
    var newID=$(this).attr('id') + i;    // This is your new id
    $(this).attr('id',newID);            // Here you are modifying attribute
});
```

**Here is example, I justed pasted same twice, one with attr `id` and other with `href`**

```js
$('.modal').each(function(i){
    var newID=$(this).attr('id') + i;
    $(this).attr('id',newID);
});


$('.className').each(function(i){
    var href=$(this).attr('href') + i;
    $(this).attr('href',href);
});

console.log($('body').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
<div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>

<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
<div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>

<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
<div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>

<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
<div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>
```

Comment: Why declare `i` use the argument of the `each` callback.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: edited, now thanks, I thought it will handy to if user is learning.

Comment: One `each()` loop is fairly enough.

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS solution.

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
var a = document.getElementsByClassName('className');
Array.from(divs).forEach(function(v, i){
  v.setAttribute('id', v.getAttribute('id')+i);
});
Array.from(a).forEach(function(v, i){
  v.setAttribute('href', v.getAttribute('href')+i);
});

console.log(Array.from(divs));
console.log(Array.from(a));
```

```html
<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
<div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>

<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
<div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>

<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
<div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>

<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
<div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>
```

or using `jQuery`:

```js
$('.className').each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + i);
  $('.modal').eq(i).attr('id', $('.modal').eq(i).attr('id') + i);
});

console.log($('body').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
  <div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>

  <a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
    <div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>

    <a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
      <div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>

      <a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal">
        <div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var index=0;
  $('className').each(function(){
    $(this).prop('id','someHref'+index);
    $(this).prop('href','#someHref'+index);
    index++;
  });
});
```

solves it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like the one from below.

```js
$("a").each(function(index){
var id = "someHref" + index;
var href = "#"+ id;

$(this).attr("href",href);
$(this).next("div").attr("id", id);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal"></a>
<div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>

<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal"></a>
<div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>

<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal"></a>
<div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>

<a href="#someHref" class="className" data-toggle="modal"></a>
<div id="someHref" class="modal fade"></div>
```